# Can I force a tr not to collapse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, tablelayout

Supposed I have code like:

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td><pre>This is line one</pre></td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td><pre></pre></td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td><pre>This is line three</pre></td></tr>
    <tr style="background-color: red"><td><pre>This is line four</pre></td></tr>
</table>
```

What I would like is for the second line to be the same height as the other lines.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML solution :

Change

```
<tr style="background-color: red"><td></td></tr>
```

to

```
<tr style="background-color: red"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

But you should really use CSS classes to set the style of your rows instead of using the "style" attribute.

Comment: I think I will use idea, but that means I actually has to change the values inside the pre tags, which I didn't want to do.  However, if there is no other option that I know, that is what I will do.

Comment: The other way is to use rcravens solution, it works, however you need to use jquery.

Comment: I am going to use yours. I will just have one extra special case elsewhere in my code, that checks for &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

Set a style on it.

```
tr{
   height: 20px;
}
```

If you want to use javascript (jQuery) then something like this.

```
var maxHeight =0;
$("tr").each(function(){
    if($(this).height()>maxHeight){
       maxHeight = $(this).height();
    } 
});

$("tr").css({height: maxHeight+'px'});
```

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xtyqr/

Comment: How would I know the height of the line?

Comment: You would have to choose a font size. Then use a tool like firebug to determine the height. If you want to do it dynamically, you will need to use some javascript.

Comment: rcravens is right. Also - give table an identifier/class and move that "background" inline style tag into css file. HTML is for content only.

Comment: I really should learn jquery sometime.  Everyone seems to use it.  That being said I think added &nbsp; is really the less time consuming solution.

Answer (score 0):

rcravens is right.

If you prefer, you can also set that height directly in the HTML:

```
<table>
<tr style="background-color: red" height = 20><td>This is line one</td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: red" height = 20><td></td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: red" height = 20><td>This is line three</td></tr>
<tr style="background-color: red" height = 20><td>This is line four</td></tr>
</table>
```

Works in Firefox 4 Beta 10

Comment: Ew, `height` is *so* deprecated, and you're declaring it really strangely! Put it in the CSS at least!

Comment: I really prefer not to make any useful decisions based on what's "depreciated," ESPECIALLY with the HTML standards, if you can even call that mess a standard...